# \columnseprule closer to one of the columns (in multicol package)

Tags: multicol

Consider a two column document (via multicol package). Does multicol package provide a mechanism to make the `\columnseprule` not exactly in the middle of the columns, but shifted a little bit (say 4pts) to the left or right?

You can use the following template (MWE):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
   \begin{multicols}{2}
   \lipsum[20]
   \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly but

[image]

the package executes `\columnseprulecolor` before the rule, and if you don't mind abusing Frank's interface, you can make this do anything...

```
%       \hss{\columnseprulecolor\vrule
%              \@width\columnseprule}\hss}%

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\renewcommand\columnseprulecolor{\hspace{-20pt}}
\begin{document}
   \begin{multicols}{2}
   \lipsum[20]
   \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't mind abusing it at all :). Thank you.

Comment: @balcinus as long as you don't moan if the interface stays but the internals change :-)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach No problem sir: then I'll abuse the new version :)